# $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] no me devuelve la URL actual

Tags: php, mvc

tengo una clase 'Router' que una de sus funciones es verificar si las urls existen en el sitio.
Este es mi index.php donde registro las rutas.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__."/../includes/app.php";
use MVC\Router;
use Controllers\PropiedadController;

$router=new Router();

//Se define la URL, se le pasa el controlador y por ultimo se le pasa un metodo de ese controlador; que construye la vista
$router->get('/admin',[PropiedadController::class,'index']);
$router->get('/propiedades/crear',[PropiedadController::class,'crear']);
$router->post('/propiedades/crear',[PropiedadController::class,'crear']);
$router->get('/propiedades/actualizar',[PropiedadController::class,'actualizar']);
$router->comprobarRutas();
```

Esta es mi clase Router

```
class Router{

    public $rutasGET=[]; //Arreglos donde se guardan las url para metodos GET
    public $rutasPOST=[]; //para metodos POST

    //Funciones que toman las urls y las guardan en un arreglo
    public function get($url,$fn){
        $this->rutasGET[$url]=$fn;
    }

    public function post($url,$fn){
        $this->rutasPOST[$url]=$fn;
    }


    public function comprobarRutas(){

        $urlActual=$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/'; //varible que guarda la ruta actual
        $metodo= $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; //variable para guardar el tipo de metodo


        //Este bloque filtra segun el metodo y guarda una funcion con el nombre de
        //alguna de las rutas guardadas en los arreglos
        if($metodo ==='GET'){
            $fn= $this->rutasGET[$urlActual] ?? null;
        }else{
            $fn= $this->rutasPOST[$urlActual]  ?? null;
        }


        if($fn){
            call_user_func($fn,$this);
            echo 'la pagina exite';
        }else{
            echo 'Pagina no encontrada';
        }
    }
```

Ya verifique que los arreglos rutasGet y rutasPOST si tengan guardadas las rutas esperadas, pasadas desde 'index.php'.
El problema esta en 'comprobarRutas'. Como pueden ver tengo la variable '$urlActual' que te deberia devolver la url en la que te encuentras, en caso contrario te devuelve '/'
Tambien verifique que el metodo si devuelva 'GET' o 'POST' segun sea el caso.
Entonces no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal que urlActual siempre me devuelve '/'.

```
$urlActual=$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/'; //varible que guarda la ruta actual
$metodo= $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; //variable para guardar el tipo de metodo
```

Comment: Echale un ojo a esta página, quizá te pueda servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635596/i-do-not-have-path-info-in-server

Comment: Yo de ti, si tienes dudas sobre las variables de $_SERVER, haria un volcado de todas sus variables y miraria las que contienen lo que esperas encontrar. En PHP normal bastaria con un `print_r($_SERVER); die();` y lo que te muestre en el navegador sera un churro de texto, pero si miras el código fuente de ese churro lo verás mejor estructurado y podras buscar mejor los datos que necesitas